# Get an InputStream from a ZipEntry from a ZipInputStream from a DocumentFile

Tags: android, zip, osmdroid, storage-access-framework

This is for an experimental Android project done in Java. What I need is to read a ZIP file from an external card (as fast as possible, if possible) and return the `InputStream` corresponding to an entry each time it is needed by an [OSMDroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) custom tiles provider.

I can do this pretty easily when serving a ZIP from the primary (or whatever it's called within their mangled filesystem) disk but when trying to read from an external card, the only option in newer versions of Android is to use their shiny [SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider).

When the path is not a relative one but a `URI` to an external card, I use a `DocumentFile` to retrieve the ZIP's `InputStream` (apparently, the only way to do it).

```
DocumentFile file = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, uri);
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
InputStream inStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(file.getUri());
```

**Question 1**: 
What would be amazing at this point, where using `DocumentFile` already took its toll on performance due to how slower it is than the good ol `File`, is to be able to have that `inStream` converted into a `ZipFile`. Or somehow directly get a `ZipFile` from `DocumentFile`. Is that possible? Maybe get a `File` from `DocumentFile` then a `ZipFile` from that?

I didn't find any solution so I went on with the `InputStream`, which I converted to a `ZipInputStream`. The problem in my code is that I can only run through it once, when what I need is to do it every time a file's stream from the Zip is needed.

```
public class MyZipFileArchive implements IArchiveFile {
    protected static ZipInputStream mZipInputStream;
}

public void init(InputStream inStream) {
    mZipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inStream);
}

public InputStream getInputStream(ITileSource pTileSource, long pMapTileIndex) {
    final String path = pTileSource.getTileRelativeFilenameString(pMapTileIndex);
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ((entry = mZipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (path.equals(entry.getName())) {
            return mZipInputStream;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Question 2**: 
The first time the `getInputStream` is called it returns what it finds but now the stream is at its end and the second time it does it, `null` is returned.

So, I need a way to either reset the stream, if possible, each time the function is called, or use another approach. I tried storing each `ZipEntry` into a `List` at the beginning, then loop through it. It doesn't work. Also, I did not find a way to convert `ZipEntry` into the `InputStream` required to be returned.

How would you tackle this? Basically, I need to use `DocumentFile` and I need to get a `ZipFile` from it or some fast way to find its entries.